# How can I pass a free-form predicate as a template function pointer argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a function that constructs a bit mask by testing a sequence of objects with a free-form predicate:

```
template<typename... Args, bool(*TestingFunc)(Object, Args...)>
inline uint32_t getMask(const std::vector<Object>& objects, Args... args)
{
    uint32_t mask = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        if(TestingFunc(objects[i], args...))
            mask |= 1 << i;

    return mask;
}
```

However, the code above does not work: gcc/clang report a `no matching function for call to` on each invocation of the function (`note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Args'` by clang, `note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:` by gcc; the invocation is `getMask<int, pred1>(objects, 10)`, the predicate is `bool pred1(Object, int)`, see information below).

There are a few well-defined predicates which accept a different number of additional arguments specific to the invocation of `getMask()`. Each predicate is a simple function. Ideally, the `getMask()` function should be written so that I could invoke it like this:

```
/* bool predicate1(Object, size_t, size_t, int, int); */
mask = getMask<predicate1>(objects, a.height(), b.width(), 10, 15);
/* ... */
/* bool predicate2(Object, int, int); */
mask = getMask<predicate2>(objects, x, y);
```

This is a hot spot in my program; the performance is critical. `getMask()` and the predicates are marked with inline. The code must be written in C++11 (not C++14 or higher).

So, how `getMask()` should be written?

Comment: Why is `TestingFunc` not a normal function parameter?

Comment: @melpomene Because I got so fixated on the idea that if my code is performance-critical and I know exactly which predicate I'm going to use in every invocation of `getMask()` then I should use function pointer as a template parameter to get compiler optimize everything. I completely failed to realize that if I were to supply my predicate as a normal function pointer, the compiler would just optimize everything anyway. Thanks, that solved my problem. I guess I'll go get some sleep; this question is left for anyone who would like to solve this with templates

Comment: @qirlib: I found a way, see answer below. But remember: Only dereferencing a single function pointer will not be the problem in you context I believe. So before thinking about manual handcrafted optimizations like yours, measure what is really the problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From c++17 you can write

```
template<auto TestingFunc, typename... Args>
inline uint32_t getMask(const std::vector<Object>& objects, Args... args)
{
    uint32_t mask = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        if(TestingFunc(objects[i], args...))
            mask |= 1 << i;

    return mask;
}
```

In C++11 you have to a lot more:

First of all, we can not use a template function as we need partial overload for it. So simply take a struct with static function:

```
struct Object
{   
    Object( int _val ):val{_val}{}
    int val;
};  

template <class F, F f> struct caller;

template <class Obj, class... Args, bool (* TestingFunc)(Obj, Args...)>
struct caller<bool (*)(Obj, Args...), TestingFunc>
{   
    static uint32_t Do( std::vector<Object>& objects, Args... args) 
    {
        uint32_t mask = 0;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
            if(TestingFunc(objects[i], args...))
                mask |= 1 << i;

        return mask;
    }
};  

bool checkit( const Object& o, int i ) 
{   
    return o.val==i;
}   

int main()
{   
    std::vector<Object> objects;
    objects.emplace_back(1);
    objects.emplace_back(2);
    objects.emplace_back(3);

// The ugly thing before c++17 is, that you have to specify the
// function type itself as a template parameter. As said: C++17
// has offered exactly the feature of auto here in template parameter lists
// to allow deduction of type from parameter.
    std::cout << caller<decltype(&checkit), checkit>::Do(objects,3) << std::endl;
}
```

But I believe that the time consuming thing is not the using of a function pointer at all. Before you manually hack a lot of things, measure, measure, measure!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the standard-library and just pass a callable of templated type by value. If it's not a function-pointer, it will be inlined.

```
template<class... Args, class F>
inline uint32_t getMask(F f, const std::vector<Object>& objects, Args... args)
{
    uint32_t mask = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        if(f(objects[i], args...))
            mask |= 1 << i;

    return mask;
}
```

And there is a very simple way to transform a function-pointer into a stateless callable, if it is a ctce:
Use `std::integral_constant<decltype(p), p>`. In C++17, maybe with a helper.

```
template <auto f>
using to_type = std::integral_constant<decltype(f), f>;

getMask(to_type<checkit>(), somedata, arg0, arg1, arg2);
getMask([](auto... x){ return checkit(x...); }, somedata, arg0, arg1, arg2);
```